# Sending mail from Erlang - OTP app or OS app

Tags: email, erlang

When I need to send occasional notification emails from an Erlang app (there's no need for the app to receive emails), I can pick one of two ways:

1. use a simple OTP app only for sending, like [esmtp](https://github.com/archaelus/esmtp)
2. use a simple (send-only) OS app like [ssmtp](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/outgoing-only.html) and make a call to it from the Erlang app via `os:cmd` and compose the message (containing information from the running system) by writing to a file from within the Erlang app.

They both work, but I don't know if there are any dis/advantages to either approach. Which is better suited for a production system?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use [AWS SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/getting-started/tutorials/send-an-email/) (Send Email Service)

there is aws erlang api to send mail via erlang [driver](https://github.com/vkletsko/eaws)

so you may send formatted or raw messages including html pages.

also you may add ses headers to see statistic about how many email have opened by customer and what clicks to they done

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/event-publishing-cloudwatch-tutorial-send-email.html